# How do I get a list of external domains/sources from a webpage

Tags: php, bash, curl

I'm looking for a way to get all external domains used for a website.

For example: **stackoverflow.com**

`googletagservices.com, google-analytics.com, fbcdn.net, i.stack.imgur.com, cdn.sstatic.net.`

Is there a way to get this list of domains in bash or php? My google-fu is failing me.

basically this list:

[image]

another example using webpagetest.org

[image]

Comment: Are you including links (I mean those in `a`s) or just js and css?

Comment: just the included assets, not external links

Comment: I won't write the full program (the question itself is a bit too broad) but I would do this in php: load the DOM, find all the `script` and `link` nodes, list their `src`/`href` attributes, find the ones that start with `https?://` (pseudo regex syntax), keep just the hostname and delete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Download The Remote WebPage
$websiteURL= "https://www.google.com";
$curl = curl_init($websiteURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$webPageContent = curl_exec($curl);
print("Download size: Of Main Page " . curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD) .''); //get the download size of page

// Match And Extract src and href Tags URLs
preg_match_all('/(?:src=)"([^"]*)"/m', $webPageContent, $matchessrc); // Get All src URLs
preg_match_all('/link.*\s*(?:href=)"([^"]*)"/m', $webPageContent, $matcheslink); // Get All link->href URLs

$matches = array_merge($matchessrc[1], $matcheslink[1]);
$domain = parse_url($websiteURL, PHP_URL_SCHEME). '://'.parse_url($websiteURL, PHP_URL_HOST);
$path = parse_url($websiteURL, PHP_URL_PATH);
$checked = array();
print_r($matches); // Print All Resources URLs
foreach($matches as $m)
{
    if($m[0] == '/')  // Convert / Pathe URL To Main Domain
        $m = $domain.$m;
    elseif(substr($m, 0, 5) != 'http:' and substr($m, 0, 6) != 'https:')
        $m = $domain.'/'.$path.'/'.$m;
    if(in_array($m, $checked)) // Remove Duplicate Resources URLS
        continue;
    $checked[] = $m; 
}
?>
```